# Get and Set References to XElement

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2015, xml-parsing

I just start using XML to LINQ at my project. But have a little problem with getting References. When i try to build i resolve errors at line `Get => XElement.Parse(RecordNew)`, Error: `: not all code paths return a value`

```
    [NotMapped]
    public XElement RecordNewXml
    {
        get => XElement.Parse(RecordNew);  <!---------here---------!>

        set => RecordNew = value.ToString();
     }

     [Column(TypeName = "xml", Order = 4)]
     public string RecordOld { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public XElement RecordOldXml
    {
        get => XElement.Parse(RecordOld); <!---------here---------!>
        set => RecordOld = value.ToString();
     }
```

Any Idea for fix this?

Comment: After adding a `RecordNew` property, that code compiles for me. My guess is that you're not using C# 7, at which point indeed it wouldn't compile. Are you using Visual Studio? If so, which version? If not, what *are* you using?

Comment: I'm using VS 2015 update 3 framework 4.7 @JonSkeet

Comment: FYI : VS 2017 community edition is free,. https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/

Comment: Right, so that's the problem. VS2015 only supports C# 6.

Comment: @JonSkeet issue Fixed with upgrading Compiler, But i'm transferring to VS 2017. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution by @JonSkeet helps, Thank you **Jon Skeet**
Now I have upgraded machine and my new pc supported VS 2017 c# 7